# When should the marriage party(Walima) be given?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, sunnah, men

It is the sunnah of Prophet(PBUH) to give Walima(marriage party).

When should a bride groom give the treat for his marriage?

I need the quickest time. ie,

> From when can a bride groom give the treat for his marriage?

Provide some references from hadiths.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has many views, but apparently the strongest view is this:

> the majority of the scholars (jumhur) are of the opinion that Walima is a meal that is prepared after the marriage has been consummated. This was the practice of the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace), as explicitly mentioned in one narration.
>
> > Sayyiduna Anas ibn Malik (Allah be pleased with him) narrates that he
> >     was a boy of ten when the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give
> >     him peace) migrated to Madina. (He added): “My mother and aunts used
> >     to urge me to serve the Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him
> >     peace) regularly, thus I served him for ten years. When the Messenger
> >     of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) passed away, I was twenty
> >     years old, and I knew about the order of Hijab more than anyone else,
> >     when it was revealed. *It was revealed for the first time when **the
> >     Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) had consummated
> >     his marriage with Zainab bint Jahsh (Allah be pleased with her). The
> >     Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) in the morning
> >     was a bridegroom, and he invited the people to a banquet.** So they
> >     came, ate, and then all left except a few who remained with the
> >     Messenger of Allah (Allah bless him & give him peace) for a long
> >     time…..* ([Sahih al-Bukhari, no. 4871](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/67/101))

Source: [sunnipath](http://qa.sunnipath.com/issue_view.asp?id=2792)

So basically, it seems that after the *nikha*, you can do the *walima* the very next morning after consummating the marriage according to the above hadith.

Comment: Asak. Consummation of marriage is not a mandatory condition for walima. There are many reasons why marriage may not be consummated between the couple on the first night.

Islam prohibits stating what goes in private between the husband & wife out in public. Those who do so intentionally are considered among the worst of people.

أَبَا سَعِيدٍ الْخُدْرِيَّ يَقُولُ  قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ إِنَّ مِنْ أَشَرِّ النَّاسِ عِنْدَ اللَّهِ مَنْزِلَةً يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ الرَّجُلَ يُفْضِي إِلَى امْرَأَتِهِ وَتُفْضِي إِلَيْهِ ثُمَّ يَنْشُرُ سِرَّهَا

Sahih Muslim 1437

Answer (score 0):

this has to do with your culture and not the sunnah. the prophet made walima after according to sunnipath answer but for aisha he offered to her milk and drank from it first before they got married,and aisha was around females i.e sort of a party.

so you can have marriage party the night before like culture